# Kinetic.JS - can't change z-index order of layers?

Tags: canvas, stack, layer, kineticjs

I can successfully change the z-index of shapes and groups, but I have so far not been able to do this for layers.

**[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TrgSf/1/)**

Instead, they seem doomed to stay in the stack order that I added them to the stage.

I've tried:

```
layer.moveToTop();
layer.setZIndex(100);
```

...but no change (even though layer nodes [*do* inherit](http://www.kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Layer.php) these methods). What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The JS Fiddle no longer works, becuase the location Kinetic JS was loaded from now returns a 404. Recommend the URL is changed to http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the layer needs to be manually redrawn before the changes take effect.

```
layer.draw();
```

As an aside, it's also worth noting that Kinetic JS does not actually honor the z-index values that you provide.  Internally, whenever setZIndex() is called, it seems to reassign z-index values from zero up to N-1, where N is the number of objects.  I believe that [this line of code in the Kinetic JS source on GitHub](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/c40fc7cf381d6273819cb5136a60672990138973/src/Node.js#L752) is what does the reindexing ...

```
this.parent._setChildrenIndices();
```